How to get secondary screen size on Android API level 34 : display.getMetrics is deprecated
I am trying to fix deprecation for API level 34 of Display.getMetrics(): here is my code in my Activity class
    val secondaryDisplay = mMediaRouter?.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO)?.presentationDisplay
    if (secondaryDisplay != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRoutePresentationDisplayChanged: name=${secondaryDisplay.name}")
        val (width, height) = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
            val displayContext = this.createDisplayContext(secondaryDisplay)
            val windowManager = displayContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
            val boundRect = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds
            Pair(boundRect.width(),boundRect.height())
        } else { // for old Android versions
            val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            secondaryDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics) // metrics will now be populated with the required data.
            Pair(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
        }

The result for old Android versions in 1920x1080 (which is correct = my beamer resolution) but the result for API level 34 is 2400x1080 which is my smartphone screen size. Gemini is lost and hallucinates. Does anyone already solved this?
